# MS Visual Studio 2005 - DOS window filling screen

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-2005

Whenever I save code while using Visual Studio 2005, an command prompt window fills the screen (very) briefly several times. I suspect it is something to do with IntelliSense. This has happened for several months now, and I don't know what initially caused it to start behaving the way it has. It is quite annoying, so I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this problem; and if so, what they did to resolve it?

[Originally asked on Stack Overflow]

Update: turns out the window in question is the VBC (Visual Basic Compiler). Any thoughts on how not to make it fill the screen?

Comment: Running on Windows XP, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since solved here: [How to stop command line program from running in full screen mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/239049/how-to-stop-command-line-program-from-running-in-full-screen-mode). Definitely worth knowing!