# How to stop command line program from running in full screen mode?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, fullscreen

I have a command line program that has somehow got set to run in full screen mode.  I want to make it run in a window instead.  How do I do this?

The details probably aren't relevant, but it's the Visual Basic compiler, a part of Visual Studio 2005.  Whenever I compile a program in VS it runs the compiler, which loads very briefly as a fullscreen program.  The flickering effect of having the screen go black everytime I compile is really annoying!

When I run the program from Windows Explorer by double-clicking it appears as fullscreen but then terminates before I can interact with it.  Is there a non-interactive way to change it to windowed mode?

Thanks.

Comment: Sidenote: It's not actually me who's having the problem, it's my co-worker.  I wrote the question in first-person, though, as it's easier to read than "My friend has this problem with his computer..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Console settings are kept in Registry (Start → Run → `regedit`), under the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` key<sup>1</sup>.

- The default settings are under `HKCU\Console` itself. Make sure the `FullScreen` value is set to `0`. If not, change it.
- Per-program settings are stored in sub-keys named according to the program's path. Look for an entry belonging to your compiler, fix it if necessary.
- You can just delete the entire `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\console` key (although you will lose the customizations you might have wanted to keep).

---

A trick you could try:

Start a long compile, and just after the full-screen switch press <kbd>Pause</kbd> on your keyboard to pause it, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to minimize the window. Right-click on its button in the taskbar, choose *Properties*, then *Options*, and select *Display Options → Window*.

---

<sup>1</sup> In `regedit`, *keys* are the folders in the left-side tree, and *values* are items in the right-side list.